# Batch rename directories removing the "&" sign

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a directory tree of folders/subfolders where I need to remove the "&" sign from their names (only the folder). I've tried the below but it doesn't work. Any ideas?
Also can you explain why it works or doesn't work.

```
@ECHO

@ECHO OFF
FOR /D %%fname IN (C:\*) 
DO (
    SETLOCAL
    SET newfname=%fname:& =%
    RENAME "%%fname" "%%newfname" 
)
```

Comment: Do not guess syntax, stick to the documentation! There is an error in almost every line of your code! Type every command followed by `/?` into a command prompt windowe to learn the correct syntax!

Comment: you can't set the `DO` on a new line like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
FOR /D %%f IN ("C:\somedir\*&*") DO (
    set "old_name=%%~nxf"
    SET "newfname=!old_name:&= !"
    REN "%%~ff" "!newfname!" 
)
```

mind that `for /d` is not recursive. Take a look also at [this](https://superuser.com/questions/475874/how-does-the-windows-rename-command-interpret-wildcards). does not handle the edge cases when a folder with the new name already exists.